How do I stop a node as it is moving around a UIBezierPath and then restart the moving from where it stopped?
See Apple DTS' solution at the bottom of this Post ...
I have an oval UIBezierPath with a moving SKSpriteNode,
I stop its motion and record the stopped position. I then restart this motion and want it to restart where it initially stopped.
Works great if motion is not stopped. Movement is great around entire oval Path.
Also works great as long as this stop-restart sequence occurs along the top half of the oval UIBezierPath. However, I have problems along the bottom half of this Path --  it stops okay, but the restart position is not where it previously stopped.
My method to create this oval UIBezierePath is as follows:
func createTrainPath() {
    
    trainRect = CGRect(x: tracksPosX - tracksWidth/2,
                       y: tracksPosY - tracksHeight/2,
                       width: tracksWidth,
                       height: tracksHeight)

    // these methods come from @DonMag
    trainPoints = generatePoints(inRect: trainRect,
                                 withNumberOfPoints: nbrPathPoints)
    trainPath = generatePathFromPoints(trainPoints!,
                                       startingAtIDX: savedTrainIndex)
            
}   // createTrainPath

My method to stop this motion is as follows:
func stopFollowTrainPath() {
    
    guard (myTrain != nil) else { return }

    myTrain.isPaused = true

    savedTrainPosition = myTrain.position
    // also from @DonMag
    savedTrainIndex = closestIndexInPath(
                                  trainPath,
                                  toPoint: savedTrainPosition) ?? 0

}   // stopFollowTrainPath

Finally, I call this to re-start this motion:
func startFollowTrainPath() {
                           
    var trainAction = SKAction.follow(trainPath.cgPath,
                                      asOffset: false,
                                      orientToPath: true,
                                      speed: thisSpeed)
    trainAction = SKAction.repeatForever(trainAction)
    myTrain.run(trainAction, withKey: runTrainKey)
    myTrain.isPaused = false

}   // startFollowTrainPath

Again, great if motion is not stopped. Movement is great around entire oval Path.
Again, no problem for stopping and then restarting along top half of oval .. the ohoh occurs along bottom half.
Is there something I need to do within GameScene's update method that I am missing? For example, do I need to reconstruct my UIBezierPath? every time my node moves between the top half and the bottom half and therein account for the fact that the node is traveling in the opposite direction from the top half?
=====  SOLVED SOLVED  =====
I placed print("pause index =", savedTrainIndex)after pausing the game and got 160, e.g. I also placed print("resume index =", savedTrainIndex) before resuming and got 160 as it should be as the node was moving along the top half of the oval.
Then, as the node was moving along the bottom half of the oval, I got 90.
Here is the response I received from Apple Deve;loper Tech Support - which worked flawlessly:
When you run the follow action on a node, SpriteKit will set the position of the node to the starting position of the provided path.
The issue you are observing (when the train makes large jumps in position) is caused because of large differences in the node’s current position compared to the follow path’s starting position.
This large difference is due to a bug in your code, specifically in the closestPointInPath function, which appears to be an algorithm that tries to determine the point on the path that is closest to the current position of the node, which you then use to calculate the starting point for the new follow path.
If you replace that function with this one (which contains a naive implementation to find the closest point to the target point), you will see that the large position jumps no longer occur:
public func closestPointInPath(_ path:UIBezierPath,
                               toPoint:CGPoint) -> CGPoint? {
        
    let targetPoint = toPoint
        
    let thePoints = getPointsForPath(path)
        
    var closestPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var minDistance = CGFloat.infinity
        
    for point in thePoints {
        let distance = distanceBetween(point, targetPoint)
            
        if distance < minDistance {
            minDistance = distance
            closestPoint = point
        }
    }
        
    return closestPoint

}

Mr. Chistie from Apple DTS is out-of-sight awesome.
Once again, I labor for 3 weeks and DTS solves the problem in 3 days.

please edit the question so it's in the form of a minimal, reproducible example. for instance you reference functions but don't include them, there are undeclared variables, etc. that said, my hunch is you're overthinking this. toggling myTrain.isPaused will pause/restart the action updates. you don't need to capture the location etc. if you wish i can post a simple example that works.

Fault .. right now I am investigating your statement about zero need to save positions. I hope it’s true since it would help on speed. I’ll be in touch. Hopefully this works with iPad rotation and showing a cycle of SKScenes in sequence.

Thanks again for your offer to help. I did not provide every func because of the size of this external library.

I am ready to ask you to post code as you offered

here is a simple example of pausing/unpausing an SKAction

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var train:SKNode = SKNode()
    let oval = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 250, y: 100, width: 300, height: 200))
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //optional: draw train path
        addChild(SKShapeNode(path: oval.cgPath))

        //train
        let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "")
        labelNode.fontSize = 70
        labelNode.zRotation = -.pi/2
        train.addChild(labelNode)
        addChild(train)
        
        //initiate a forever action on `train`
        var choochoo = SKAction.follow(oval.cgPath,
                                          asOffset: false,
                                          orientToPath: true,
                                          speed: 100)
        choochoo = SKAction.repeatForever(choochoo)
        train.run(choochoo)
    }
    
    //pause and unpause the actions executing on `train`
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        train.isPaused.toggle()
    }
}

